# SQL: Select records that meet a grouped minimum value criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

[image: Image for clarity]

I want to use SQL to write a query that returns all rows for a security ID whose minimum date is at least 12-Mar-2013. That is, select only those securities which have price coverage after a specific date. Please see the image for more clarity.

Can someone please guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)'

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   yourtable b
               WHERE  a.security_ID = b.security_Id
               HAVING Min(b.date) >= '2013-03-12')
```

if your database engine supports `Over` clause then

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Min(date)OVER(partition BY security_ID) AS MinDate
        FROM   yourtable)a
WHERE  MinDate >= '2013-03-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below query

```
 SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE SECURITY_ID NOT IN(
 SELECT SECURITY_ID FROM YOURTABLE WHERE CONVERT (DATE,DT)< '12-MAR-13' GROUP BY SECURITY_ID)
```